# How do I exit less when reading from stdin when it is called with a single minus argument: "less -"

Tags: less, stdin, exit

Is there a proper way to exit `less -` without having to kill the process?

I accidently created a file called `-` (minus) and tried to view it with:

```
less -
```

Less than follows stdin and I did not find any way to exit it properly. I had to `ctrl-z` and kill the process. Is there some sort of escape char or any other way to exit `less -` without killing it?

PS: I know the proper way of viewing a file called `-` is `less ./-`.

Comment: This sequence seems to work : **a**, **Enter**, **Ctrl-C**, **q** after you just started **less**. Better than **Ctrl-Z**, but I cannot say it's a **proper** way.

Comment: Stepping down to the end of the screen with multiple presses of `Enter` will give you a `:` prompt that you can type `q` at to quit.

Comment: @Philippe That works, if you don't press `ctrl-c` without any input. Which is what I unfortunately did.

Comment: @Kusalananda This always works. Even after I messed up @Philippes way by pressing `ctrl-c` straight away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Not sure why @Kusalananda didn't submit this as an answer.)

Hold `Enter` until the cursor reaches the bottom of the window. Then the expected `:` will appear, and pressing `q` will quit.

Comment: You may need to press Ctrl+C to start anyway.  Then pressing "G" then "q" should also work, and faster.

Comment: @Ned64 doesn't work for me, you have to go through the `Enter` routine